# Yahoo pipes - obtaining only image and description

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I'm trying create my own rss feed from site free.zoznam.sk via yahoo pipe. Feed for this site is created via feed43.com/
For source code lets talk about this one video http://free.zoznam.sk/video/Specialny-preskok-1350927332

Now I need to pull out only the description and an image of the video, and ignore the rest.

The description can be obtained from:

```
<meta
   name="description"
   content="už od začiatku to vyzeralo na problém. Zábavné videá online na Free.sk. Pridaj aj svoje video!"
/>
```

or

```
<!-- eTarget ContextAd Start -->
  už od začiatku to vyzeralo na problém
<!-- eTarget ContextAd End -->`
```

or

```
<input
   type="hidden"
   name="module_description"
   value="už od začiatku to vyzeralo na problém"
/>
```

And the source of the image of the video is:

```
<link
   rel="image_src"
   href="http://free.zoznam.sk/openMedia.php?path=e70fc312077202556dd3e5261adbcd49a2502b0eabc95423473527e6ef3df9467a4730bface6b045720aa361b2fd1874"
/>
```

Here is my pipe http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=d08fe4bb311f8681c2e007966cdf6226

It's working, but how can I remove the irrelevant stuff from the source like:

```
<div style="width:640px;">

<div class="popisb" style="background-image:none;width:640px;margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;height:auto;">

etc...
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you need XPath fetch. I'll leave someone with better knowledge of pipes to take it from there...